# firebase firestore audit log in functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, stackdriver

I have a couple of http functions in my firebase project, because I prefer to hydrate, validate and update the data on the backend. I would like to use the automatic stackdriver logs, but I need to associate the log events with the authenticated user (the requests are authenticated). Is there any way to add some context to database updates? Or commit the changes in the name of the user (not the service account)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore triggers don't currently associate any information about the end user (not even if you're using Firebase Authentication and security rules), so you will have to write user information into each document in order to track who performed an action on it.  It will not just appear in the environment or context.

If you go this route, I strongly suggest adding security rules that require the user to provide their Firebase Auth UID correctly in a document field, so you can be 100% sure it's correct.

Read this for more details: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/patterns-for-security-with-firebase-per-user-permissions-for-cloud-firestore-be67ee8edc4a